# Will High Side IGBT Driver work with high ripple power supply?

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, mosfet-driver, igbt, ripple

The Vdrive voltage in the below circuit is supplied from rectified mains, including filter caps. The problem is that filter caps for this kind of application get expensive really fast, so I am considering including only two 1000 uF caps.

With that, there would be up to 20 V ripple on Vdrive at max load.

My question is if I can get away with that. I am especially worried about the driver circuit for the high side IGBTs. Would this circuit be able to switch the transistors in spite of the high ripple?

[image: circuit]

Comment: It looks like to work. I haven't check the numbers in the datasheet, but looked at the example circuit in the datasheet. Meantime, what I can guess is: Are you building a H bridge to control the direction?

Comment: @jay yes, the purpose of this H Bridge is to control the direction. I also intend to use it for controlling a motor's speed with PWM.

Comment: So, you are controlling PWM by SD, just curious? What you would check is the drive capability (V & I) of HO, LO, HO-VS for Q1, and LO-COM for Q2, The device high-side drive circuitry is interesting. The internal block diagram does not detail it.

Comment: Hey, I read the datasheet, looking for how VB gets biased, but could not find it. You may want to test the device on a bread board. Meantime, in my experience, it is better to synchronize to the line, though it depends on your applications. That case, there are better solutions. You can use thyristors, too.

Comment: Yes, I think the best option right now is to test the circuit. Now, what do you mean by synchronizing the line? And I do intend to control the PWM with the SD ports.

Comment: Oh, the PWM can be synchronized to the Line frequency. That removes aliasing with the line frequency. Think about it, since you cannot give enough filtering, you possibly see harmonics, could be any frequency noticeable.

Comment: One came in mind; It makes more sense to connect D3 anode to Vdrive. Try it carefully, if the initial circuitry does not work. High voltage on IGBT gate will damage the device.

Comment: @jay, I have been trying to simulate this in LTSpice, but Infineon Spice models are apparently not very reliable.

Comment: Ha ha.. I like LTSpice. Though, I get reasonable simulation results only for simple ones.